# Show Energy-momentum operator transforms as a tensor under Lorentz transformations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, inertial-frames, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I know, from my professor notes, that a general field operator can transform under Lorentz as
$$U(\Lambda)\hat{\mathcal{O}}^r(x)U^\dagger(\Lambda)=\hat{\cal{O}}^{r'} {M(\Lambda)_{r'}}^r$$ where $M(\Lambda_1\Lambda_2)=M(\Lambda_1)M(\Lambda_2)$. Where does this relation come from?

Then I have to show that
$$U(\Lambda)\hat{\tau}_{\mu\nu}U^\dagger(\Lambda)=\hat{\tau}_{\mu'\nu'} {\Lambda^{\mu'}}_{\mu}{\Lambda^{\nu'}}_\nu$$
namely, this transforms as a tensor.

I started at the infinitesimal level where
$${\Lambda^\mu}_\nu=\delta^\mu_\nu-\omega^\mu_\nu$$ and $$U(\Lambda)=\mathbf{1}-\frac{1}{2}i\omega_{\mu\nu} \hat{M}^{\mu\nu}$$
I don't know how to proceed with this calculation. I tried substituting these two relation for the infinitesimal level but I can't reach any good result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regards to your first question, that is, in fact, a definition. To appreciate it, let's recall what a representation is. Let $G$ be some group. A representation of $G$ is a pair $(V,D)$ where $V$ is some vector space and where $D:{G}\to{\rm GL}(V)$ is a map associating to every group element $g$ one linear transformation $D(g)$ satisfying the condition: $$D(g_1)D(g_2)=D(g_1g_2).$$

The idea of a representation is simple. A group, by itself, is one abstract entity which encodes a set of elements with a composition law. A representation is a way in which these objects can actually be realized as concrete transformations acting linearly on a vector space. As you may imagine for the same group (i.e., the same underlying abstract pattern of composition) there are many actual concrete realizations. That is the case for the Lorentz group where we can find scalar, vector, tensor and spinor representations.

Now, let $V$ be one vector space carrying a representation $D:{\rm SO}(1,3)\to {\rm GL}(V)$ of the Lorentz group ${\rm SO}(1,3)$. A quantum field transforming in the representation $R$ is any set of operators $\Phi^a(x)$ where $a=1,\dots, \dim V$, such that under the unitary representation $U(\Lambda)$ of the Lorentz group on the theory's Hilbert space, the condition $$U(\Lambda)\Phi^a(x)U(\Lambda)^{\dagger}=D(\Lambda^{-1})^a_{\phantom a b}\Phi^b(\Lambda x)\tag{1}$$
holds true. Here $D(\Lambda)^a_{\phantom a b}$ is the matrix representative of the transformation $D(\Lambda)$ in some basis chosen for the representation space $V$.

Regarding your second question, it's not very clear the context (you want to show that a specific stress-energy tensor transforms as it should or a general one starting from some definition?). In any case, I'll give you one example. A massless scalar field has stress-energy tensor $$T_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu \phi^\ast \partial_\nu \phi-\dfrac{\eta_{\mu\nu}}{2}\partial_\sigma\phi^\ast \partial^\sigma \phi.\tag{2}$$

Moreover, a scalar field operator obeys, by definition $$U(\Lambda)\phi(x)U(\Lambda)^\dagger = \phi(\Lambda x).\tag{3}$$

In that case you can derive how $\partial_\mu \phi(x)$ transforms by taking a derivative of (3). Then you can construct $U(\Lambda)T_{\mu\nu}(x)U(\Lambda)^{\dagger}$ and use the transformation you derive for $\partial_\mu \phi(x)$ to evaluate it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I see the point for the second part: I was trying to prove the transformation for a generic stress energy tensor but now I guess I need a specific one (which in my case is indeed the massive real scalar field). For the first part, now I read everything with care. It's my first time studying these topics so it's a bit hard to understand the abstract part of groups and representations. Thanks again!

Comment: I have a problem. When you say to take the derivative of (3) to get $\partial_\mu \phi(x)$ I don't know how to take the derivative of the LHS. Namely how can I take the derivative of $U(\Lambda)$? Thanks

Comment: I'm glad the answer helped you ! Regarding your first comment I suggest you take a look into the book "Quantum Field Theory for Mathematicians" by Robin Ticciati. Despite the name it is accessible to physicists and it covers the basics of representation theory (which is important in QFT). I also strongly recommend studying at least the first 5 chapters of Weinberg's The Quantum Theory of Fields, Volume 1. Regarding the second comment, the operator $U(\Lambda)$ doesn't depend on $x$, so the derivative only acts on the field.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I will cover that part on those books. My professor follows the Mandl Shaw books and I didn't find enough "math" about representations.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately most QFT texts don't include much about representation theory. The unitary representations of the Poincaré group, which are very important to understand what are the possible one-particle Hilbert spaces, is usually not discussed in detail in most books. AFAIK this is only covered in depth in Weinberg's textbook (chapter 2). Representations of the Lorentz group are often discussed, but without giving the proper representation theory background.

Comment: Thanks! I have a new question related to the condition you give in equation (1): my professor uses the matrix representation written as ${M(\Lambda)_b}^a$, so I guess this is an inverse matrix. In you definition we have ${R(\Lambda)^a}_b$ which is exactly what I expect to have. What are the differences?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake on my part. Indeed one actually has $R(\Lambda^{-1})^a_{\phantom a b}$. But since $R$ is a representation $R(\Lambda^{-1})=R(\Lambda)^{-1}$ and I think in the end it is consistent with your lecture notes. I'll correct the post. The precise reference is Chapter 5 of Weinberg (more precisely equations 5.1.6 and 5.1.7).

Comment: Now, regarding the motivation for defining it with the $R(\Lambda^{-1})$ on the RHS instead of $R(\Lambda)$, I think is a matter of convenience. At least in Weinberg's context (which is what I have access to), what he will do next is to connect the Lorentz representation in which the field transforms to the Poincaré representation under which particle states transform. This leads to equations (5.1.19) and (5.1.20). I believe the point of his definition is that in said equations, with his convention, we don't have one inverse on the RHS.

Comment: Thank you, now I give a look! Is this related to active and passive Lorentz transformations? On Ticciati's book I found $U^\dagger(\Lambda)\phi^a(x)U(\Lambda)={D^a}_b(\Lambda)\phi^b(\Lambda^{-1}x)$. So these are two different transformations? I can't get this part..

Comment: No, Ticciati's formula is actually the same. Since $U(\Lambda)$ is unitary $U(\Lambda)^\dagger = U(\Lambda^{-1})$. This means that if you call $\tilde{\Lambda}=\Lambda^{-1}$ Ticciati' formula reads $$U(\tilde{\Lambda})\phi^a(x)U(\tilde{\Lambda}^{-1})^\dagger = D^{a}_{\phantom a b}(\tilde{\Lambda})\phi^b(\tilde{\Lambda x})$$ which is Weinberg's formula.

Comment: Oh, I got it! Thanks for your patience, this is all new stuff for me!

Comment: No worries ! I'm glad I was able to help. QFT takes some time to get used to. BTW, I strongly recommend the first five chapters of Weinberg's textbook. They made many things make a lot more sense when I was begining with QFT as well. His textbook is hard, but it's really worth the effort.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, so is it correct to say that $\partial_\mu \phi(\Lambda x)={\Lambda^\nu}_\mu\partial_\nu \phi(\Lambda x)$ ?

Comment: Sorry for taking long to reply, I have been in a conference this week. This is actually all about the chain rule. To make it clear perhaps it is useful to denote $y = \Lambda x$. Then the chain rule tell us that $$\dfrac{\partial \phi(\Lambda x)}{\partial x^\mu}=\dfrac{\partial \phi(y)}{\partial y^\nu}\dfrac{\partial y^\nu}{\partial x^\mu}.$$ But $y^\nu = \Lambda^\nu_{\phantom \nu \mu}x^\mu$ and thus $$\dfrac{\partial \phi(\Lambda x)}{\partial x^\mu}=\Lambda^\nu_{\phantom \nu \mu}\dfrac{\partial \phi(y)}{\partial y^\nu}\bigg|_{y=\Lambda x}.$$

Comment: So your equation is correct but it is important to understand that on the left hand side $\partial_\mu \phi(\Lambda x)$ is the derivative with respect to $x^\mu$ of $\phi(\Lambda x)$ whereas on the right hand side $\partial_\nu \phi(\Lambda x)$ is actually $\partial_\nu \phi$ evaluated at $\Lambda x$. The two things are different.

Comment: Thanks for you reply! That's exactly the things that was haunting me. On the left I have the derivative wrt $x^\mu$ and on the right it is with respect to the new $y$ variable.. are there no problems in doing that?